# Testing multiple INDEX/MATCH results without looking at them

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to identify each column header and then test it against another set of criteria without actually showing the results.

Example:
Everybody's been asked to put together a bowling team (of four people). Each team must include at least one female. Everybody counts themselves and then enters a "Y" for the other three members of their team.

I need a formula that identifies the four members of the team and then checks them against a master gender list and return "True" if there is a female.

[image: datasheet]

Comment: How is your master gender? A header Male (in a column) another Female and names below

Comment: Please could you add screenshots of your datasheets to clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @FredaK: [Please don’t ask people to post images of text.](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/23408)  Instead, encourage them to post a textual representation of their data, as was done [here](//superuser.com/q/889201/150988) and [here](//superuser.com/q/892744/150988); suggesting that they use the [Format Text as Table](https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/) site if they want to.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it using a helper row.
You can add it above / below your range, keep it up to date using a formula and also hide it.
The formula in the helper row:
`=IF(INDEX($N$3:$N$11,MATCH(B2,$M$3:$M$11,0))="f",1,0)`

The formula to check whether the team includes at least one woman:
`=SUM((B3:J3="y")*($B$1:$J$1))>0`
This is an array formula, so press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after typing it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all who looked at and considered a response. As I continued to work on this problem yesterday I concluded that I was approaching this incorrectly. I ended up modifying the table layout - essentially placing the "y's" on the X-axis.
The final formula entails much more than what I initially asked but finally I found that the SMALL function was key; in this version, I set it up to return the value for each occurrence (I only expected three) and created one formula for each. After that, I paired it with an HLOOKUP and if an Error was returned then. viola!

=IF($L8="+",IF(AND(ISERROR(HLOOKUP(INDEX(INDIRECT("tables!"&ADDRESS(79,55+MATCH(E$6,tables!$BD$78:$CL$78,0))&":"&ADDRESS(130,55+MATCH(E$6,tables!$BD$78:$CL$78,0))),SMALL(IF(tables!$BC$79:$BC$117=$K8,ROW(tables!$BC$79:$BC$117)-ROW(INDEX(tables!$BC$79:$BC$117,1,1))+1),**1**)),$E$2:$K$3,1,FALSE)),ISERROR(HLOOKUP(INDEX(INDIRECT("tables!"&ADDRESS(79,55+MATCH(E$6,tables!$BD$78:$CL$78,0))&":"&ADDRESS(130,55+MATCH(E$6,tables!$BD$78:$CL$78,0))),SMALL(IF(tables!$BC$79:$BC$117=$K8,ROW(tables!$BC$79:$BC$117)-ROW(INDEX(tables!$BC$79:$BC$117,1,1))+1),**2**)),$E$2:$K$3,1,FALSE)),ISERROR(HLOOKUP(INDEX(INDIRECT("tables!"&ADDRESS(79,55+MATCH(E$6,tables!$BD$78:$CL$78,0))&":"&ADDRESS(130,55+MATCH(E$6,tables!$BD$78:$CL$78,0))),SMALL(IF(tables!$BC$79:$BC$117=$K8,ROW(tables!$BC$79:$BC$117)-ROW(INDEX(tables!$BC$79:$BC$117,1,1))+1),**3**)),$E$2:$K$3,1,FALSE))),"","X"),"") as a  CSE.

Answer (score 0):

I have a slight variation on [Máté’s answer](//superuser.com/q/1179926/150988#1180972).

- Create a helper row that simply duplicates Column `M`, the “gender” column,
  but transposed (putting each person’s gender in their column). 
  For example, using Row 24, put

  ```
  =INDEX($M$1:$M$10, COLUMN())
  ```

  into Cell `B24` and drag/fill to the right, to Column `J`. 
  We don’t need to use `MATCH()` because,
  if (for example) we are in Column `F` (i.e., Column 6),
  which is Bob’s column, then Bob’s gender is in Row 6. 
  And we don’t need to do an `IF()`
  because we can test the value in the next step.

  As in Máté’s answer, you can hide this helper row if you want to.

  Alternatively, you can eliminate Column`M` altogether
  and simply store the genders in a row.
- Somewhere on Row 2 (for example, Cell `N2`), enter the formula

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:J2="y"), --(B$24:J$24="f"))
  ```

  `SUMPRODUCT()`, as its name suggests,
  multiplies some things and then adds the products. 
  It does essentially the same thing as Máté’s
  `SUM(range1*range2)`,
  but it doesn’t need to be entered as an array formula. 
  Since Máté didn’t explain his answer:
  this looks at each column in the range `B`-`J` (the columns for the members). 
  It looks at the current row (shown as `2`)
  to see whether the member (corresponding to this column)
  is a member of the team corresponding to this row. 
  And it looks at Row 24 to see whether the member is female. 
  Use `--` to convert `TRUE` to `1` and `FALSE` to `0`. 
  Multiply them to get a `1` for each member who is on this team and is a female;
  then add those ones and zeroes to get the number of females on the team.

  And, of course, drag/fill down to Row 10.

[image: spreadsheet]

And, of course, you can test whether the count is 0,
possibly with conditional formatting.